# Entity in entity relationship diagram

Tags: entity, entity-relationship

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) "An entity may be defined as a thing which is recognized as being capable of an **independent existence** and which can be uniquely identified". I don't get this independent existance because I've been given examples of entities such as "fees" or a "house sale", you can't have fees without taking a "class" and no "house sale" without having a house. Where am I confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you - I don't think **independent existence** adds much to the definition.

It is better to think of an entity as something you might wish to store information about e.g.

```
order
order history
customer
supplier
order item
address
address history
```

N.B. entities are never pluralised

Answer (score 0):

According to the german version of your article, an entitiy can be described as an "object" within the real world, which can be described with certain attributes.
e.g. a driver's license can be an entity, even if it's is rather abstract, because it can be described with attributes.